# UI for node.js and jquery web

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

1. Does `node.js` (considering a web application) have any preferred UI framework? Or it's an orthogonal issue to using `node.js`?
2. jQuery is nice, is jQuery UI the most used UI framework with jQuery engine? Could you point me at any other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Node does not care about UI, it's all server side.

2) Jquery UI is probably the most used UI framework with jQuery engine, although I do not have numbers to back that up.

[Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/) is another good one that is built on top of jQuery.

[jQuery Tools](http://jquerytools.org/) I have heard good things about, never used it though. It is also built on top of jQuery (obviously).

Answer (score 2):

NodeJS was conceived as a server side solution, but that hasn't stopped people from trying to make standalone solutions for UIs. One such solution is "[Node Webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit)", which provides a webkit based application that leverages nodejs for writing 'client' side apps.

If you are hoping to use NodeJS in the same way as JQuery, then you are looking at the wrong tool for the job. NodeJS should be seen as an application framework for JS based applications.

Answer (score 0):

[Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) is not a clientside web application, it's a javascript runtime for servers. It has no GUI.

For alternatives to jQuery UI you might have a look at [jQuery Plugins vs UI vs some alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2001902/1048572).